# Delphi: Change the font of links TLinkLabel

Tags: delphi, label, linklabel

How do I change the font of the link TLinkLabel?
For example, I want that the size of this link was 10 and the color blue: 
[image: TLinkLabel]
I'm trying to change this way:

```
LinkLabel1.Font.Color:=clBlue;
LinkLabel1.Font.Size:=10;
```

,but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `TLinkLabel` react on changes to its font property you have to set `UseVisualStyle := false`.

Note: you cannot have different fonts for static text and the link text. The rendering is done by Windows internally and there are no means to influence this.

Comment: Thank you. This reacts to changes in font size and face, but not to colour. Any ideas? Of course <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)">here</a> was too much to expect :)